# Floating Input Labels Using GreenSock (GSAP)

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, gsap

I'm trying to create floating input labels using GreenSock. I want to be able to keep the labels at the top if the input field has a value, if not then return label back in place.

Right now the the animation only runs one time and on just one input element. Need help figuring out how I can do this for each input.

```
// SETUP
const tl = new TimelineMax();
const container = $(".input-container");

// CLICK EVENT
container.on("click", function() {

  // VARIABLES
  const label = $(this).find(".label");


  // TWEEN
  tl.to(label, 0.35, {left: "5", top: "1", transform: "scale(.75)", color: "#333"});  

});

// FOCUSOUT EVENT
container.on("focusout", function() {

  const input = $(this).find(".input");
  if (input.val() === "") {
    tl.reverse();
  }

});
```

Heres what I have so far: **[Demo Link]**[1](https://codepen.io/Armandot6/pen/vWQYGY)

Comment: Why, has design won over usability once again? https://medium.com/simple-human/floating-labels-are-a-bad-idea-82edb64220f6

Comment: @CBroe Thats debatable, I'm just practicing using GreeSock anyways. http://mds.is/still-floating-labels/

Comment: Ok, fair enough. You still owe us an actual problem description though. [ask].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is, that you're using the same `TimelineMax` object for all of the labels. Each input/container will need its own Timeline.

You could perhaps attach the Timeline instance directly to the DOM like this:

```
// SETUP
const container = $(".input-container");

// CLICK EVENT
container.on("click", function() {

  // VARIABLES
  const label = $(this).find(".label");

  this.tl = new TimelineMax();
  // TWEEN
  this.tl.to(label, 0.35, {left: "5", top: "1", transform: "scale(.75)", color: "#333"});  

});

// FOCUSOUT EVENT
container.on("focusout", function() {

  const input = $(this).find(".input");
  if (input.val() === "") {
    this.tl.reverse();
  }

});
```

[Updated CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qVQNWL)

Comment: Ah, makes since, I was closer then I thought. Thanks!

Comment: I tried changing it from .on('click', to .on('focus' but can't get it to work any idea? Thanks again!

Comment: use `focusin` instead of just `focus`

Comment: You're the best, looks like I need to work on my jquary/JS